# Sliced background image with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, sass, background

This is my first question so I'm probably gonna miss something. Please tell me if you need any additional information.

I am trying to create a sliced image overlaying another image and when you hover any of the slices it will disappear and show the underlying picture. What I've done is that I have created several divs that represents each slice and then used a fixed background position so the overlaying image looks whole.

I've made the concept work, but I'm having some trouble adjusting the positioning of the overlaying picture. Since I'm using fixed background positioning the overlaying picture doesn't work in a responsive environment, that is if I don't position the image in the top left corner. But if I remove the fixed positioning I haven't been able to create a seamless sliced picture.

Can this be solved or am I approaching this problem the wrong way entirely? Thanks for your help!

Here is a codepen of what I've done https://codepen.io/renryl/pen/MzJjpd.

```
body {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

$itemWidth: 20px;
$foreground-image: 'https://i.warosu.org/data/biz/img/0022/15/1495964000552.jpg';
$background-image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wiiu/images/5/5e/New-Super-Mario-Bros-Art-21-400x400.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121029024830';

.background-picture {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(#424242,.5) url($background-image) no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.foreground-picture {
  width: $itemWidth;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(#424242,.5) url($foreground-image) no-repeat fixed;

  &:hover{
    transition: all 0s linear;
    opacity:0;
  }
}

<html>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <picture inline-template>
        <div class="background-picture">
        <div v-for="i in numberOfSlices" :key="i" class="foreground-picture"></div>
  </div>
    </picture>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


Vue.component('picture', {
  data() {
      return {
         numberOfSlices: 20
      }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, You need both of these properties:

> background-position: center;

This will center your image to your div.

> background-size: cover;

The background-size cover will fit to the content and cover it all

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I set those to properties the foreground image is "zoomed" in. Is there any way to do this while keeping the size/resolution of the image?

Comment: From MDN for background-cover: 'Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.' If you want the image to be responsive, then it's going to have to 'zoom' in to fill all available space. Otherwise you'll have a gap at the sides or top of the image

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @paddyfields :)